# Google BigQuery: In Python, column addition makes all the other columns Nullable

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a table that already exists with the following schema:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "mode": "required",
        "name": "full_name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "mode": "required",
        "name": "age",
        "type": "integer"
      }]
  }
}
```

It already contains entries like:

```
{'full_name': 'John Doe',
          'age': int(33)}
```

I want to insert a new record with a new field and have the load job automatically add the new column as it loads. The new format looks like this:

```
record = {'full_name': 'Karen Walker',
          'age': int(48),
          'zipcode': '63021'}
```

My code is as follows:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client(project=projectname)
table = client.get_table(table_id)

config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
config.autoedetect = True
config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
config.schema_update_options = [
    bigquery.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION,
                               ]

job = client.load_table_from_json([record], table, job_config=config)
job.result()
```

This results in the following error:

> 400 Provided Schema does not match Table my_project:my_dataset:mytable. Field age has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE

I can fix this by changing `config.schema_update_options` as follows:

```
    bigquery.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION,
    bigquery.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION
                               ]
```

This allows me to insert the new record, with `zipcode` added to the schema, but it causes both `full_name` and `age` to become `NULLABLE`, which is not the behavior I want. Is there a way to prevent schema auto-detect from changing the existing columns?

Comment: JL I just tried changing to `config.autodetect = False` but that did not affect the error.

Comment: JL, without  ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION I get the `Field age has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE` error as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add fields to your schema, you can do the following:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

table = client.get_table("your-project.your-dataset.your-table")

original_schema = table.schema   # Get your current table's schema
new_schema = original_schema[:]  # Creates a copy of the schema.
# Add new field to schema
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField("new_field", "STRING")) 

# Set new schema in your table object
table.schema = new_schema   
# Call API to update your table with the new schema
table = client.update_table(table, ["schema"])
```

After updating your table's schema you can load your new records with this additional field ignoring any schema configurations.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way to do this without manually specifying the schema for the new column? I'd like to take advantage of the autodetect without losing the required mode of my existing columns.

Comment: @Xiphias I dont think this is gonna work without field relaxation. Autodetect assumes your fields are nullable because the schema inference is done using a sample of your data (up to 100 records) which makes impossible for the autodection algorithm to conclude if your field is required or nullable,