# BigQuery - Is the source code for schema update available?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to add a column in a BigQuery Table and order it according to my preference (instead of just appending it to the end of the table). I know that if I use ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION when loading data to the table, it will result in whatever order I want (e.g. column_A, NEW_COLUMN, column_B).

Question is, can I replicate `ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION` behaviour? Is there a source code to what a BQ Job does when using this parameter?

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545371/add-a-column-to-a-bigquery-schema-but-not-at-the-end) and [ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182294542#comment2)

Answer (score 1):

The Closest I can find that is similar function as ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION is the answer here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62508787/19378826)

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

table = client.get_table("your-project.your-dataset.your-table")

original_schema = table.schema   # Get your current table's schema
new_schema = original_schema[:]  # Creates a copy of the schema.
# Add new field to schema
new_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField("new_field", "STRING")) 

# Set new schema in your table object
table.schema = new_schema   
# Call API to update your table with the new schema
table = client.update_table(table, ["schema"])
```

(A python Job)